# Validate string in regular expression

Tags: javascript

I want to have a regular expression in JavaScript which help me to validate a string with contains only lower case character and and this character `-`.

I use this expression:

```js
var regex = /^[a-z][-\s\.]$/
```

It doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: can you show examples of good/bad strings?

Answer (score 5):

**Just use**

```js
/^[a-z-]+$/
```

---

**Explanation**

- `^` : Match from beginning string.
- `[a-z-]` : Match all character between `a-z` and `-`.

  - `[]` : Only characters within brackets are allowed.
  - `a-z` : Match all character between `a-z`. Eg: `p,s,t`.
  - `-` : Match only strip (`-`) character.
- `+` : The shorthand of `{1,}`. It's means match 1 or more.
- `$`: Match until the end of the string.

---

**Example**

```js
const regex= /^[a-z-]+$/

console.log(regex.test("abc")) // true
console.log(regex.test("aBcD")) // false
console.log(regex.test("a-c")) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var regex = /^[-a-z]+$/;
```

```js
var regex = /^[-a-z]+$/;
var strs = [
  "a",
  "aB",
  "abcd",
  "abcde-",
  "-",
  "-----",
  "a-b-c",
  "a-D-c",
  " "
];
strs.forEach(str=>console.log(str, regex.test(str)));
```

Comment: This regex can contain spaces unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
/^[a-z-]*$/
```

it should match the letters a-z or - as many times as possible.

What you regex does is trying to match a-z one single time, followed by any of -, whitespace or dot one single time. Then expect the string to end.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
let regex = /^[a-z\-]+$/;
```

Then:

```
regex.test("abcd") // true
regex.test("ab-d") // true
regex.test("ab3d") // false
regex.test("") // false
```

PS: If you want to allow empty string `""` to pass, use `/^[a-z\-]*$/`. Theres an `*` instead of `+` at the end. See Regex Cheat Sheet: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```js
var regex = /^[a-z|\-|\s]+$/ //For this regex make use of the 'or' | operator

str = 'test- ';

str.match(regex); //["test- ", index: 0, input: "test- ", groups: undefined]

str = 'testT- ' // string now contains an Uppercase Letter so it shouldn't match anymore

str.match(regex) //null
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
var str = 'asdadWW--asd';

console.log(str.match(/[a-z]|\-/g));
```